# ServerClick event fires Page.Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Lately i realized a problem in asp.net, which appears kinda strange to me.

I got an `sample.aspx` file:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="sample.aspx.vb" Inherits="SampleProj.sample" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <input type="image" id="Accept" runat="server" class="accept-btn" src="/Images/accept.png" />
</asp:Content>
```

And the related codebehind file `sample.aspx.vb`:

```
Public Class sample
   Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
'Some code here
End Sub

Private Sub Accept_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles Accept.ServerClick
'Some code here
End Sub
```

So my Problem is easily explained: Upon clicking the accept button the `Accept.ServerClick` event is fired as expected, but for some reason (even though the page IS NOT reloaded) the `Page.Load` event is fired too. This is my first asp project and maybe this is an expected behaviour, but i found neither an explanation nor a way to disable it. Any information would be appreciated.

Greeting, Ohemgi

(If you find any errors this is caused by writing this short sample. My code is compiling and running without a problem, so my question is only about the load event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly fine. From **MSDN** Documentation:

> After a page has been posted back, the page's initialization events (Page_Init and Page_Load) are raised, and then control events are processed.

If you do something in the Page_Load that you don't want to do every time you click a button, just wrap it inside this condition:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    // Some code here. It is executed only once.
}
```

You can find more information in the links below:

1. [ASP.NET Web Server Control Event Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually was exactly the information i was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

VB.Net version

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' Some code here. It is executed only once.
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Normally people should be able to transform from c# to vb since both are .net based ;) But thanks for your effort +1